# Bump Distortion implementation in xcode for IOS using swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-image, distortion

in apple documentation under Core Image Filter Reference i have found `CICategoryDistortionEffect` it has `CIBumpDistortion` but it says only Available in OS X v10.4 and later.

is there any way that i can use it on iOS ? and if so , what is the code in Swift ?

thank you ..

Answer (score 0):

CIBumpDistortion was added in iOS 6.  It should work fine.

Comment: can you help me with the code please i am beginner in Swift ,Thank you :D